# Warning: Division by zero in Opencart 1.5.5.1

Tags: php, opencart

Get this error: Division by zero in /home/xxxxxx/domains/onlineshop.ge/public_html/catalog/controller/module/lpbc.php on line 135

on line 135 I have this code for saving percentage:

```
'saving'    => round((($subresult['price'] - $subresult['special'])/$subresult['price'])*100, 0),
```

It seems like I have 0.00 price for some products, but I haven't.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Where is this `$subresult` coming from? Could you post your changed code? Did you try to do `var_dump($subresult);` before you calculate `saving`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below code line instead of your it code line & then Check it.

```
'saving'    => $subresult['price'] == 0 ? 100 : round((($subresult['price'] - $subresult['special'])/$subresult['price'])*100, 0),
```